# Custom property could not be mapped by EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I want to create a simple ordering system. As every ordering system, my system should work with stock, orders and so on. The core entity representing SKU is `Sku.cs`:

```
public class Sku
{
    public Sku(Guid id, string name,
      string description, decimal price,
      byte[]? photo)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Price = price;
        Photo = photo;
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Price { get; private set; }
    public byte[]? Photo { get; private set; }
}
```

To work with stock I need to know how many pcs of every SKU left on stock. So I created an entity `StockItem.cs`:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public StockItem(Sku sku, uint stockBalance) : this(stockBalance)
    {
        Sku = sku;
    }

    private StockItem(uint stockBalance) : base()
    {
        StockBalance = stockBalance;
    }

    [Key]
    public Sku Sku { get; private set; }
    [Required]
    public uint StockBalance { get; private set; }
}
```

Now, when I run Add-Migration everything messes up and I get the following error:

```
The entity type 'StockItem' requires a primary key to be defined.
```

Ok, but I definitely used `[Key]` annotation in `StockItem.cs`. So what if I add `modelBuilder.Entity<StockItem>().HasKey(s => s.Sku);` to `OnModelCreating`? Error changes to this one:

```
The 'Sku' property 'StockItem.Sku' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter.
```

And that's it, I have no idea what to do next. So how can this problem be solved and what's the matter? Is it just poor entity design or something else?

Comment: In stockItem just use normal int is as primary key and skuId as foreign key.

Comment: @Timofeus can you please provide an example of how skuId can be configured as foreign key?

Comment: my ef is a bit rusty, look here https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/hasforeignkey-method